# Can we get title of youtube video in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, video, youtube

Can anybody tell me, is it possible, to get the title of youtube video from their youtube url in angularjs. In my project , i need to save my uploaded youtube url in database and but my problem is , i only save url of video ,not the title of youtube video.Please tell me if any body have idea.

I checked lot of examples, they talked about ,the below url,: https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/"+videoid+"?v=2

i used the above url, in angular controller with http get method.

```
$http.get(https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/"+videoid+"?v=2).success(function(data)
    {
    console.log(data)
    });
```

It return 410 error. Please help me.

Comment: Google's YouTube API docs can be found here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started also, yout code snippet has some errors, such as missing quotes.

Comment: Follow this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478391/get-youtube-videos-title-with-jquery-using-youtube-api?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: i used above url, it shows, 410 error